# Reference original html elements in nested JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question that is a flaw in my understanding of JQuery.

```
$('input').focus(function() {

    $('.popup').click(function() {
        //How do I reference the original input that 
        //triggered the focus event here?             
    });
});
```

As you can tell from the title, I had problems searching for an answer  to this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a reference like this:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    var originalInput = $(this);
    $('.popup').click(function() {
        console.log(originalInput.val());          
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    var orig = $(this);
    $('.popup').click(function() {
        //How do I reference the original input that 
        //triggered the focus event here?             
        console.log(orig);
    });
});
```